# Ajax, javascript, prompt, funciones

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, prompt

Quiero que en el prompt solo permita valores enteros del 1 al 5, y si es correcto todo se ejecute el ajax. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?
Porque cuando lo hago detecta que solo sean esos valores, pero al presionar **cancelar** en el *prompt* o **aceptar** el error en el *alert*,  de igual manera se ejecuta el ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calificar(idpd,vc1){
        var cant = parseInt(prompt("Calificar del 1 al 5",1));
    if (Number.isInteger(cant)){
      if (cant <1 ){alert("El valor es incorrecto, reintentar");};
      if (cant >5){alert("El valor es incorrecto, reintentar");};
      }else{alert("Recuerda: Sólo números");};
    var paramet ={ 
      "idpd" : idpd,
      "cant" : cant,
      "vc1"    : vc1
    };
  $.ajax({
    data: paramet,
    url: './calificar.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (){
      alert("Guardado");
    }
      });  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás enviando la alerta sin detener la ejecución de la función. Podrías agregar un `return;` después de cada alerta o, mejor aún, tener el flujo adecuado, ejecutando la petición AJAX solo si se introdujo un valor válido.

Cuando se presiona el botón cancelar. [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) devuelve `null` y es lo que se puede usar para evitar mostrar alertas.

```js
function calificar(idpd, vc1) {
    // Definir una variable adicional para obtener la respuesta
    let resp = prompt("Calificar del 1 al 5",1);
    // Comparación por tipo y valor (estricta, 3 signos =)
    if(resp === nul) {
        // El usuario canceló, salir de función
        return;
    }
    let cant = parseInt(resp);
    if (Number.isInteger(cant)){
        // Es un entero, analizar si se puede continuar
        if(cant >= 1 && cant <= 5) {
            // El valor está entre 1 y 5, se puede ejecutar la petición
            var paramet ={ 
                "idpd" : idpd,
                "cant" : cant,
                "vc1"    : vc1
            };
            $.ajax({
                data: paramet,
                url: './calificar.php',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (){
                    alert("Guardado");
                }
            });
        } else {
            // El valor está fuera de los límites
            alert("El valor es incorrecto, reintentar");
        }
    } else {
        // El valor no es entero
        alert("Recuerda: Sólo números");
    };
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me fue muy útil, pero me pregunto como haría para que cuando presione **cancelar** no salga ```alert("Recuerda: Sólo números");```

Comment: Listo, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!, funciona bien.